# Parsing text in dictionary

Tags: python-3.5, string-parsing

I have a dictionary which has following text:

```
{
        "body": "Customer: \"I have a big problem. You cut off my head!\"\r\n\r\nMe: \"I'm sorry? How did I cut off your head?\"\r\n\r\n(The customer shows me an obviously self-taken picture, with the top of his head removed.)\r\n\r\nMe: \"Sir, it looks like it was taken that way.\"\r\n\r\nCustomer: \"No it wasn't! My whole head was there when I took it. I'm sure!\"\r\n\r\nMe: \"Okay, let me see your memory card...\"\r\n\r\n(The customer hands it to me, and I go in the lab and pull it up on the computer. Sure enough, he chopped his own head off in the picture.)\r\n\r\nMe: \"Sir, that is the whole image, and the top of your head isn't in it.\"\r\n\r\nCustomer: \"But it's DIGITAL, can't you fix it?\"\r\n\r\nMe: \"You can't create something from nothing.\"\r\n\r\nCustomer: \"But... but... but... I need a photo for a dating website!\"\r\n\r\nMe: \"Give me the camera and go stand over there.\"\r\n\r\nCustomer: *excited* \"Hot d***! You can be my best man!\"\r\n\r\nMe: \"A thank you card will be enough.\"\r\n\r\n(Skip ahead 9 months...)\r\n\r\nFemale customer: \"Is your name ***?\"\r\n\r\nMe: \"Yes, can I help you?\"\r\n\r\nFemale customer: \"My husband wanted you to have this.\" *hands me an envelope*\r\n\r\n(I open the envelope, and sure enough there's a thank you card with a picture of him and his wife. He actually got married and sent her in with the card!)",
        "category": "Men / Women",
        "id": 18189,
        "title": "A Heady Proposition"
    },
```

But I am not sure at all how to parse the text for `body` so that I can get a readable text from above.

I am looking for a general solution instead of parsing based on keywords like `Customer` and `Me`

The text should look as following image:
[image]

Comment: Why is  parsing based on keywords like Customer and Me off-limits?

Comment: As there other similar texts which have similar structure but different keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You can split by the delimiter pattern `\r\n\r\n+`

Using the `re` and `pprint` modules: 
`pprint(re.split('\r\n\r\n+',your_dict['base']))`
generates:

```
['Customer: "I have a big problem. You cut off my head!"',                                                               
 'Me: "I\'m sorry? How did I cut off your head?"',                                                                                      
 '(The customer shows me an obviously self-taken picture, with the top of his '                                          
 'head removed.)',                                                                                                       
 'Me: "Sir, it looks like it was taken that way."',                                                                      
 'Customer: "No it wasn\'t! My whole head was there when I took it. I\'m '                                               
 'sure!"',                                                                                                               
 'Me: "Okay, let me see your memory card..."',                                                                           
 '(The customer hands it to me, and I go in the lab and pull it up on the '                                              
 'computer. Sure enough, he chopped his own head off in the picture.)',                                                  
 'Me: "Sir, that is the whole image, and the top of your head isn\'t in it."',                                           
 'Customer: "But it\'s DIGITAL, can\'t you fix it?"',                                                                    
 'Me: "You can\'t create something from nothing."',                                                                      
 'Customer: "But... but... but... I need a photo for a dating website!"',                                                
 'Me: "Give me the camera and go stand over there."',                                                                    
 'Customer: *excited* "Hot d***! You can be my best man!"',                                                              
 'Me: "A thank you card will be enough."',                                                                               
 '(Skip ahead 9 months...)',                                                                                                  
 'Female customer: "Is your name ***?"',                                                                                 
 'Me: "Yes, can I help you?"',                                                                                           
 'Female customer: "My husband wanted you to have this." *hands me an '                                                  
 'envelope*',                                                                                                            
 "(I open the envelope, and sure enough there's a thank you card with a "                                                
 'picture of him and his wife. He actually got married and sent her in with '                                            
 'the card!)']
```

You can now print this array line by line to a PDF using the module [pyPdf](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2), with a nice font of your choice - achieving the look above +-.

You'll need to add further code to add some formatting, such as the italics above; e.g.: 
Anything before a `:` should be bolded, and any line holding `)(` should be italicized.